# Node create with automatic title

Tags: drupal

I have a contentype called - X
I have another content type called - Y
I have a view that lists all content types = X ; created by the logged in user

How could I add a button next to each listing that will take the user to the create content type = Y  page and automaticlly fill in the title as its specified in content X.

thanks
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [prepopulate module](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) to automatically fill in form fields. Next, you use views to create a link field which builds the link including the prepopulate syntax.

Comment: Can you explain the views link field in more detail. Im note sure I understand ? When I add the node:link field, how can I get that to link back to the create content type ?

Comment: A node:link field always links to the node itself, so you can't use that here. What you need is a node:title field, because the title is what you are selecting from the database. Once you have that, check the "Output this field as a link" box and enter `node/add/contenttypeY?edit%5Btitle%5D=[title]` as link path. (Note that you are escaping the square brackets as %5B and %5D to prevent Views from replacing it with the actual title; see http://drupal.org/node/578772#comment-2201032 to understand what's going on.)